# Laravel artisan command make file trace

Tags: php, makefile, laravel-5.6, laravel-artisan

I'm new in Laravel and trying to make some artisan command feature like

`artisan make:controller`

so I try to trace how `make:controller`  work , I thought I could find it at  `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php`
 but not

where should i found it?

Comment: it's in[`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! This is very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

## 2020 Update

#### Laravel 7

you can find the file here :
[`https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.html`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/Console/ControllerMakeCommand.html)